# Add barButtons to navigationbar with modalView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, modalviewcontroller

In my application, I'm presenting a modalViewController with a navigationbar on the top of it, but I'm not able to add barbuttons to the navigatiobar. I'm using following code:

```
displayController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *cntrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:displayController];

[displayController setTitle:@"TEST"];


UIBarButtonItem *submit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                            target:self
                            action:@selector(displayViewForPosts)];

displayController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = submit;
[submit release];

UIBarButtonItem *newsfeed = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(displayViewForPosts)];
displayController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newsfeed;
[newsfeed release];

[self presentModalViewController:cntrol animated:YES];
[cntrol release];
[displayController release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIViewController *detailViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *cntrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

[detailViewController setTitle:@"TEST"];


UIBarButtonItem *submit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(displayViewForPosts)];
detailViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = submit;
[submit release];


[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:cntrol animated:YES];
[cntrol release];
```

Comment: Thanx Aaron for your reply, but it's still not working.. I've edited my question with updated code.. Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What problems are you having? Is the modal view still not showing?

Comment: No, modalview was showing up earlier too.. I don't know how but suddenly the buttons appeared.. Thanx for your help..

Comment: Ok, there's a problem.. These buttons are showing up like normal toolbar buttons with no direction as the navigationbarbuttons. I wanted those type of directional buttons which will be better for user.

Comment: I am looking at this and more and more I thing you dont want to use  presentModalViewController, I think you just want to push the new view onto the existing navigationController stack.

was there a reason you choose presentModalViewController?